# Changing the format of coordinate text (with datetime) in status bar of a Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, format

From the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212134/how-to-display-all-the-informations-of-a-scatterplot-dot-with-pick-event-when-us), I have developed another code which uses Matplotlib in place of Seaborn (The data are plotted on several figures and subplots, and so are now more readable and I am closer to the point I want to reach: the user by putting the cursor over a point has access to all the information of the point, in particular the datetime.)

Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

from datetime import datetime

# size of the database
n = 1000

nA = 4
nB = 9

no = np.arange(n)
date = np.random.randint(1e9, size=n).astype('datetime64[s]')
A = [''.join(['A',str(random.randint(1, nA))]) for j in range(n)]
B = [''.join(['B',str(random.randint(1, nB))]) for j in range(n)]
Epsilon1 = np.random.random_sample((n,))
Epsilon2 = np.random.random_sample((n,))
Epsilon3 = np.random.random_sample((n,))

data = pd.DataFrame({'no':no,
                     'Date':date,
                     'A':A,
                     'B':B,
                     'Epsilon1':Epsilon1,
                     'Epsilon2':Epsilon2,
                     'Epsilon3':Epsilon3})


def format_coord(x, y):
    string_x = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    return 'x={}, y={:.4f}'.format(string_x,y)

def plot_Epsilon_matplotlib():
    
    for A in data['A'].sort_values().drop_duplicates().to_list():
        
        n_col = 2
        
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(np.ceil(nB/n_col).astype(int),n_col)
        
        for j, B in enumerate(data['B'].sort_values().drop_duplicates().to_list()):
            
            df = data.loc[(data['A']==A) & (data['B']==B)]
            df = df.sort_values("Date", ascending=True)
            
            axes.flatten()[j].plot(df["Date"],df['Epsilon1'],marker='x',c='b',label="Epsilon1")
            axes.flatten()[j].plot(df["Date"],df['Epsilon2'],marker='x',c='r',label="Epsilon2")
            axes.flatten()[j].plot(df["Date"],df['Epsilon3'],marker='x',c='g',label="Epsilon3")
            
            axes.flatten()[j].format_coord = format_coord

if __name__ == '__main__':

    plot_Epsilon_matplotlib()
```

The goal is that when the user puts the cursor over a point, he gets access to the full datetime of the data.

- I have first tried to change the major formatter (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib)):

  ```
  axes.flatten()[j].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
  ```

  but then the x ticks are not readable (especially if the user zooms on a subplot)
- I then tried the define my own format_coord as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750332/change-format-of-coordinate-text-in-status-bar). My first try is given in the full code given above. The format of the datetime in Matplotlib figure status bar is good but the date remains in 1970 !
- After reading [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64), I realized this problem relates on Numpy datetime64 to Datetime conversion. I then coded this new version of format_coord (strongly inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921593/11405523)):

  ```
  def format_coord_bis(x,y):
      dt64 = np.datetime64(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x))
      unix_epoch = np.datetime64(0, 's')
      one_second = np.timedelta64(1, 's')
      seconds_since_epoch = (dt64 - unix_epoch) / one_second
      string_x = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch).strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
      return 'x={}, y={:.4f}'.format(string_x,y)
  ```

  but the date given in the status bar remains the 01/01/1970...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49267147/11405523).

The function format_coord() should be defined as follows:

```
def format_coord(x, y):
    string_x = matplotlib.dates.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return 'x={}, y={:.4f}'.format(string_x,y)
```

[image]